# Putting a constant char in a char matrix

Tags: c++

I have a char matrix (relation[][]) and I want to put some character in several items of that. look:

```
char relation[num_obj][num_obj];
for(k1=0; k1<num_obj; ++k1)
  for(k2=0; k2<num_obj; ++k2)
   if(k1 != k2)
    if(Top[i][j]==1)
     {     
      strstr((const char *)relation[i][j], "T");
      strstr((const char *)relation[i][j], "B");
      }
```

k1,k2,num_obj are some defined variable.
As you see I am trying to put some constant char (like " T, B) to some elements of matrix, but I receive this warning:

```
warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

Can any one help me in removing this warning.
Thanks in advance and all the best :)

Comment: Why c++? I think this is purely a C problem.

Comment: `relation[i][j]` is a `char` and you are trying to cast it to `const char*`, what effectively is an attempt to cast an integer to a pointer.

Comment: you are right, It is a piece of a big c++ program but this part is a C problem as you told. Now can you tell me how remove this problem?

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please. This code makes no sense. `strstr()` does not modify anything, the only useful part of its call is the return value (which you ignore). `relation` is a 2D array of `char`, `"T"` is a srting (an array of `char`s, not a `char`). Please explain clearly what you actually want.

Comment: Barry solved my problem by the below answer. Thank all of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just trying to write a `'T'` into the array, that's just assignment:

```
relation[i][j] = 'T';
```

[`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) is a method to find a substring in a string. It's only useful for its return-value, so even if you got your code to compile, it just wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Oh, you are right. at the First I tried: relation[i][j]="T" and I got this error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]
then I tried to remove this error by using strstr((const char *) and receive above warning, but I must use 'T' instead of "T"... it works! thanks a lot :)

Comment: @shirin `'T'` is a `char`, `"T"` is a `const char[2]`.

Comment: Ya, I had a mistake, now I understood the difference.